# ASP.NET How to convert array objects converted to string back to the array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hey I have the following function,

```
        Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("webdirect", New Object() {Company, LocationCode, CustomerNumber, OrderNumber, OrderRef, OrderDate, WebLines})
        o_Company = CType(results(1),System.Nullable(Of Integer))
        o_LocationCode = CType(results(2),String)
        o_CustomerNumber = CType(results(3),String)
        o_OrderNumber = CType(results(4),String)
        o_OrderStatus = CType(results(5),String)
        o_OrdDescrip = CType(results(6),String)
        RespLines = CType(results(7),webdirect_RespLinesRow())
        Return CType(results(0),String)
```

So the return type of this function is a string, but I would like to get it back to its original form so I can access the individual sections i.e. o_LocationCode,o_CustomerNumber, etc how can I do that ?

Further Edit

Entire functions looks like this

```
Public Function webdirect(<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByVal Company As System.Nullable(Of Integer), <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByVal LocationCode As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByVal CustomerNumber As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByVal OrderNumber As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByVal OrderRef As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType:="date", IsNullable:=true)> ByVal OrderDate As System.Nullable(Of Date), <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(IsNullable:=true), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("WebLinesRow", IsNullable:=false)> ByVal WebLines() As webdirect_WebLinesRow, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByRef o_Company As System.Nullable(Of Integer), <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByRef o_LocationCode As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByRef o_CustomerNumber As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByRef o_OrderNumber As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByRef o_OrderStatus As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=true)> ByRef o_OrdDescrip As String, <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(IsNullable:=true), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("RespLinesRow", IsNullable:=false)> ByRef RespLines() As webdirect_RespLinesRow) As <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("result", IsNullable:=true)> String

Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("webdirect", New Object() {Company, LocationCode, CustomerNumber, OrderNumber, OrderRef, OrderDate, WebLines})
o_Company = CType(results(1),System.Nullable(Of Integer))
o_LocationCode = CType(results(2),String)
            o_CustomerNumber = CType(results(3),String)
            o_OrderNumber = CType(results(4),String)
            o_OrderStatus = CType(results(5),String)
            o_OrdDescrip = CType(results(6),String)
            RespLines = CType(results(7),webdirect_RespLinesRow())
            Return CType(results(0),String)
        End Function
```

Called like this

```
        Dim returnArray As String

    returnArray = client.webdirect(10, "123", "123", "123", "147", "2011-11-1", webLinesArray, 10, "", "", "", "", "", webRespArray)
```

No errors on run time but the string seems to be just blank, thats why i was wondering how I convert the string back to the array so I can access the individual elements.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. The return value is *not* "array objects converted to string" (as mentioned in the title), it's simply the first array element converted to string.

Comment: You should provide an example of the input and output.

Comment: Is this not an array of objects i.e. Dim results() As Object which is then Converted to string  Return CType(results(0),String) ?

Comment: Edit First posts with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just return the array?

```
Return results
```

Comment: Hey Jakub, its a function like I posted in my edited original post now, this is a proxy function from a WSDL referenced to my visual studio project. The return type seems to be string not sure if i can change this function